# Printing JavaScript Quiz Results on a new page on clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

On clicking submit I want the score and the correct answers to be printed on a new page. Right now the score pops up on an alert box. How can this be done in HTML/JavaScript ?

The code for my quiz application is :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Quizzer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background:#E3E1DC;
            font-size:16px;
            font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            line-height:1.2em;
            color:#222222;
        }

        pre {
            font-family:Consolas, Courier;
            font-size: 12px;
            color:#444444;
            line-height:12px;
            margin-left:30px;
            margin-top:-28px;
        }

        .instructions {
            margin-left:25px;
        }

        .button {
            margin-left:10px;
            margin-bottom:120px;
            width:200px;
            height:50px;
        }

        .question {
            background:#F1E6D4;
            padding:15px;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .odd {
            background:#9F9694;
        }

        .wrong {
            border-left:#BA3D49 5px solid;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script langauge="JavaScript">
        // number of questions in the quiz, this must be set exactly
        var totalQuestions = 5;

        // arrays to store answers, and user submited answers.
        var answers = new Array;
        var userAnswers = new Array;

        // quiz answers
        answers[1] = "B";
        answers[2] = "C";
        answers[3] = "D";
        answers[4] = "D";
        answers[5] = "B";

        // sets the users answer selection to the appropriate array element
        // in the userAnswers array.
        // questionNumber is the question div id as well as the userAnswers
        // array element index to store the answer in.
        // answerSelection is the value of the selected answer from a question
        function SetAnswer(questionNumber, answerSelection) {
            userAnswers[questionNumber] = answerSelection;
        }

        // applies the .wrong class styling to any question div that is incorrect
        function MarkIncorrectQuestions() {
            for(i = 1; i <= totalQuestions; i++) {
                if(answers[i] != userAnswers[i]) {
                    document.getElementById(i).className += " wrong";
                }
            }
        }

        // counts the number of correct answers
        // returns the number of correct answers
        function GetScore() {
            var score = 0;
            for(i = 1; i <= totalQuestions; i++) {
                if(userAnswers[i] == answers[i])
                    score++;
            }
            return score;
        }

        // sets classes for each question div to its default styling.
        function ApplyDefaultQuestionStyles() {
            for(i = 1; i <= totalQuestions; i++) {
                if(i % 2 == 0) {
                    document.getElementById(i).className = "question";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(i).className = "question odd";
                }
            }
        }

        // calls all appropriate functions in order to check answers and mark
        // incorrect questions.
        function CheckQuiz() {
            ApplyDefaultQuestionStyles();
            var totalQuestions = '5';
            var score = GetScore();
            MarkIncorrectQuestions();
            alert("You scored: " + score + " out of " + totalQuestions + ".");
            //document.write("<h1>hello</h1>");
        }

    function result(score,totalQuestions){
              document.write("Score" +score);
            }

    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="ApplyDefaultQuestionStyles()">
    <div class="instructions">
        <h1>The Movie Quiz</h1>

    </div>

    <form>
        <div id="1">
            <p><strong>Question 1</strong></p>
            <p>Where does “It’s a Wonderful Life” take place?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="A" onClick="SetAnswer(1, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Bedford Hills</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="B" onClick="SetAnswer(1, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Bedford Falls</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="C" onClick="SetAnswer(1, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Bedford Lake</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="D" onClick="SetAnswer(1, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Bedford City</p>
        </div>

        <div id="2">
            <p><strong>Question 2</strong></p>
            <p>In “The Godfather,” who was murdered in the causeway?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="A" onClick="SetAnswer(2, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Luca Brasi</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="B" onClick="SetAnswer(2, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Moe Greene</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="C" onClick="SetAnswer(2, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Sonny</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="D" onClick="SetAnswer(2, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Paulie</p>
        </div>

        <div id="3">
            <p><strong>Question 3</strong></p>
            <p>Where did Princess Leia hide the stolen plans for the Death Star?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="A" onClick="SetAnswer(3, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">In C-3PO</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="B" onClick="SetAnswer(3, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">In a pocket in the hem of her white gown</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="C" onClick="SetAnswer(3, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">In the Millennium Falcon</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="D" onClick="SetAnswer(3, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">In R2-D2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="4">
            <p><strong>Question 4</strong></p>
            <p>In which of the following films did Robert Duvall NOT appear?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="A" onClick="SetAnswer(4, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">To Kill a Mockingbird</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="B" onClick="SetAnswer(4, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">The Godfather</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="C" onClick="SetAnswer(4, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Tender Mercies</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="D" onClick="SetAnswer(4, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">One Flew Over the Cuckoo’s Nest</p>
        </div>

        <div id="5">
            <p><strong>Question 5</strong></p>
            <p>Who was Scarlett O’Hara’s second husband?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="A" onClick="SetAnswer(5, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Frank Kennedy</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="B" onClick="SetAnswer(5, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Rhett Butler</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="C" onClick="SetAnswer(5, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Ashley Wilkes</p>
            <p><input type="radio" value="D" onClick="SetAnswer(5, this.value)" name="radiobutton2">Charles Hamilton</p>
        </div>
        <p>



        <input type="submit" class="ui-button" onClick="CheckQuiz()" value="Submit Answers" name="submitButton" class="button"></p>


    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options instead of using an alert ...

1) Create a layered popup that pops up in front of all your page content (you could darken the BG as well like most modals do). This would allow you to pop the message up in the same page and not require the user to open another window.

2) Your other option would be to popup a new window and use javascript to write the information to that window. See the following link for more information on this: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/write-content-dynamic-javascript-popup/

I personally would go with the first because it guarantees that it will work even if the user has a popup blocker.